# How can a conforming C++ implementation indicate that it doesn't know the current date and time?

Tags: c++, time, language-lawyer, c++-chrono, c++20

Some C++ implementations (for instance, battery-powered embedded devices) may have no use or no way for tracking the current date and time.

The *C standard* specifically allows for such implementations. To quote from ISO/IEC 9899:1999 7.23.2.4 (emphasis mine):

> The time function returns the implementation’s best approximation to the current
>   calendar time. **The value (time_t)(-1) is returned if the calendar time is not
>   available.**

C++11 introduced the `chrono` library and the `std::chrono::system_clock::now()` function for getting the wall clock time from the system-wide realtime clock. The function is declared as `noexcept`, so it cannot throw any exception to indicate unavailability nor does it allow returning any special value (like `-1` in the case of C).

But with C++11, C++14 and C++17 there was still a loophole. The standard didn't specify the clock's epoch, so a conforming implementation could set the epoch to the point in time when it was powered on (or the program was started) and still satisfy the requirements of the standard.

The current draft of C++20 will close that loophole and require `system_clock` to use Unix time. In other words, a C++ implementation that doesn't know the current time is non-conforming.

Is this an oversight by the standards committee? How can a conforming C++ implementation indicate that it doesn't know the current date and time?

(Note that in other parts of the standard this problem is solved. For instance, an implementation may set the `__TIME__` and `__DATE__` macros to an implementation-defined value if the real time and date is not available.)

Comment: Welp. Looks like a C++ implementation that cannot provide the current meatspace time would be non-conforming. That's not really a showstopper. It is not entirely unprecedented for special-purpose C++ implementation not to support this thing, or that thing. I wouldn't be surprised if a C++ implementation that's targeting some embedded platform doesn't have a `std::thread`, for example.

Comment: Are you asking about freestanding implementations specifically, or hosted ones with possibly no time facilities?

Comment: Perhaps a compiler targeted at an architecture that does not support time should not implement `system_clock` at all?

Comment: @StoryTeller Both. Freestanding implementations, however, could get around this by not providing the 'chrono' library at all (which would also exclude all other clocks).

Answer (score 20):

There is a distinction to be made between knowing the time, and knowing *the correct time*.

If such a device is turned on, it may freely assume that its CPU cycle counter (or whatever powers `steady_clock`) represents the number of cycles since UNIX time. That is, it can assume that it was powered on at the moment of the UNIX epoch. That would be a valid implementation of `system_clock`. That time will likely not be correct in some absolute sense, but it will be a conforming C++20 implementation.

The standard simply requires `system_clock`'s epoch to be UNIX time (or more specifically, we can all assume that it is UNIX time). That doesn't mean the tick count retrieved for the clock is guaranteed to be the globally accurate current time. After all, the user can technically *change* the current time, which is meant to be reflected in `system_clock` (which is why it is not required to be a steady clock).

As such, you could never assume that `system_clock` accurately represented the current time; it only represents what the operating environment *thinks* is the current time. So there is no way for `chrono` to explain that the current time is or is not "correct" in some sense.

`system_clock` is basically meant to provide whatever is the closest to the correct time-of-day that the system can provide or understand. If the best the system can do is to assume that the device was turned on at the UNIX epoch, then that's what you get.

Furthermore, since `system_clock` (and all of `<chrono>` for that matter) is not on the [list of freestanding requirements](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/compliance), C++ implementations for such devices could be freestanding implementations. And therefore they choose not to implement `system_clock` (or all of `<chrono>`) at all.

Comment: Interesting. So it could be the correct time, the incorrect time or even some fixed dummy time the device is set to when powered on that in no way correlates to any real time and it would still be conforming.

Comment: If a freestanding implementation implements everything from `chrono` except `system_clock` it would still be conforming, right? There is no requirement in the standard that _if_ a header is provided that it has to be provided fully, right?

Comment: @Norask: `<chrono>` is a header, not a library. There is only one standard library. And yes, for freestanding implementations, not all parts of a header have to be provided. That's why I said, "And therefore they choose not to implement `system_clock` (or all of `<chrono>`) at all.".

Comment: The accuracy of timing functions is a Quality of Implementation issue.  There are many ways in which a conforming implementation could be of such poor quality as to be useless.  A good quality implementation should report the time reasonably accurately when practical, but the fact that the returned time is off by an hour or even a decade would not make an implementation non-conforming.

Comment: 1. "That is, it can assume that it was powered on at the moment of the UNIX epoch" - That's not the same as the previous sentence, and AFAICT you can't assume the CPU was powered on at the UNIX epoch. 2. If you refer both to `steady_clock` and `system_clock` you should say something about their difference; perhaps you could consider only referencing one of them to make things simpler.

Comment: @einpoklum: "*That's not the same as the previous sentence*" Unless its CPU clock counter doesn't start when it's powered on, I fail to see the difference. And even in that case, the difference is pretty trivial. "*you can't assume the CPU was powered on at the UNIX epoch*" Um... why not? All you would need to do is return the CPU cycle tick count from your `system_clock`. What in the standard prevents this?

Comment: @NicolBolas: That assumptions extends to things like "then XYZ must have happened while the system is up", "then if a program on this system indicates it's been running since power up, then it's been running for at least X years" and so on. I just suggest you remove that implication.